# MySQL - How to select data by vowels range

Tags: mysql, database

We have a database with a table whose values were imported from another system and i want to developed a query by find out min vowels to max vowels
Is there a MySQL Regular expression to do this ?

```
select name from user where name REGEXP '^[a,e,i,o,u]${2,5}';
```

i tried with this query but i failed.

Comment: Need minimum verifiable example data showing sample and what should match and what should not.

Answer (score 1):

Find the occurrence of each vowel character by taking the difference of the whole string length and length of the string without that vowel character.

**Query**

```
select `name`, (
    length(`name`) - length(replace(lower(`name`), 'a', '')) +
    length(`name`) - length(replace(lower(`name`), 'e', '')) +
    length(`name`) - length(replace(lower(`name`), 'i', '')) +
    length(`name`) - length(replace(lower(`name`), 'o', '')) +
    length(`name`) - length(replace(lower(`name`), 'u', ''))
) as `vowel_count`
from `your_table_name`
order by 2;
```

**[Find demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19968a/1)**

Comment: This worked great for me. Thanks.! I was able to easily modify this for my purposes.

Comment: @ Wanderer i need your help again, I had a similar problem for count character. I want to get the only characters value of min and max range. I think this is explained better with an example. Example- The column of table is username like abc123,12def,erogan44e etc. i want the select only characters length between min to max.

Is it possible without using procedure ? Should we use regular expression ?

Comment: @ritwik : means for `abc123` output should be `3` right?

Comment: @ Wanderer : Do you have any idea ? how to make query without procedure ?

Comment: @ritwik : Post it as a new question.